# How to hide duplicate records in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have Post table

```
╔════╤═════════╤═══════╤══════════════╤══════╗
║ id │ user_id │ title │ created_date │ rate ║
╠════╪═════════╪═══════╪══════════════╪══════╣
║ 1  │ 1       │ text  │ 10/12/2020   │ 5    ║
╟────┼─────────┼───────┼──────────────┼──────╢
║ 2  │ 1       │ text  │ 10/12/2020   │ 4    ║
╟────┼─────────┼───────┼──────────────┼──────╢
║ 3  │ 2       │ text  │ 10/12/2020   │ 3    ║
╟────┼─────────┼───────┼──────────────┼──────╢
║ 4  │ 2       │ text  │ 10/12/2020   │ 5    ║
╚════╧═════════╧═══════╧══════════════╧══════╝
```

I want to group posts by created date and select posts only with a lower rate so result should be

```
╔════╤═════════╤═══════╤══════════════╤══════╗
║ id │ user_id │ title │ created_date │ rate ║
╠════╪═════════╪═══════╪══════════════╪══════╣
║ 2  │ 1       │ text  │ 10/12/2020   │ 4    ║
╟────┼─────────┼───────┼──────────────┼──────╢
║ 3  │ 2       │ text  │ 10/12/2020   │ 3    ║
╚════╧═════════╧═══════╧══════════════╧══════╝
```

Firstly I tried to select them with this:

```
SELECT posts.*, MIN(rate) FROM posts GROUP BY created_date;
```

And got the error: "ERROR column 'posts.id'" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

I added after GROUP BY id,

```
SELECT posts.*, MIN(rate) FROM posts GROUP BY id, created_date;
```

but it helped only hide the error and after this sql I got the same result I showed in the first table

Are there other methods to do such things?

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (created_date) p.*
from posts p
order by created_date, rate asc;
```

You seem to want one row per date, the one with the lowest rate.  `distinct on` chooses one row per combination of keys in the parentheses.  Which row is based on the ordering in the `order by`.

If you want duplicates, then use `rank()` or a subquery:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             rank() over (partition by created_date order by rate) as seqnum
      from posts p
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```